# S3 "code": "NetworkingError", "errno": "ECONNREFUSED"

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

Trying to make an stream upload to Amazon S3 from a EC2 instance. I have added the user to  security policy of S3 Full access which comes given by Amazon which looks as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also added CORS to look like this allowing any host to make POST, PUT or GET requests:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>

   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Still getting this error when try to upload.

```
"code": "NetworkingError",   "errno": "ECONNREFUSED"
```

Comment: Do you have any sort of IP whitelist instituted? This sounds like an actual IP type issue.

Comment: Agreed. "Connection refused" is definitely not going to be an authentication, policy, or CORS-related error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems ok now. The issue wasn't in the S3 AWS itself but in my EC2 instances that runs a Python script to render some files from a 3D software. When writing the output there was not permission in the path so when tried to pass the parameter to the S3UploadFile service it was causing this error.

So basically **if parameters you send are not right you may get this kind of error in the S3 side**. You better check the origin error log from the request was made.

Thanks!